# How to configure a cluster?

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing

I'm new to development using **Cassandra**.

I have a problem regarding creating Cluster. I initialized all my credentials but could you please see the following error:

```
Error provisioning cluster: Unable to SSH some of the hosts.
Unable to SSH to 127.0.0.1
global name 'get_output' is not defined.
```

Why am I getting this error? Also, I have given `localhost` loop `ip` for `Nodes`. Is that correct?

And I also had a problem executing `setup.py` to enable `SSL`.

My Machine Specs

```
OS - Windows 8 64bit
x64 based Processor.
```

Please guide me. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to run ssh service on your Windows machine. Cassandra requires ssh connectivity between participating nodes including the localhost.

Comment: Thank you @user3088572, ill try to fix it with Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD). If there is any better program, please let me know.